# EXCEL VBA - Need to filter, and then autofill a value from the second row down to the lowest row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to autofill the rest of the rows down to the lowest row with values in it. Looking at other posts and my own research and testing I created a code. However, my code has a filter and these filter values change over time. As you can see in the code, I am selecting AB2 and inserting Yes, and then autofilling to the bottom, or to lowest value in column Z. However sometimes due to the filters No and Yes, the second row might be AB3 or even AB4. Is there a way I am able to automate this function, where I can place the value Yes under the first row and then autofill it down without having to change the number next to AB every time.

```
Columns("F:H").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$F$1:$H$13889").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="No"
ActiveSheet.Range("$F$1:$H$13889").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Yes"
Range("AB2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Yes"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AB2:AB" & Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it, since you never know where to start writting your "Yes":

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    
    'Assuming you are running the code on the same workbook it is written
    'change SheetName for the sheet name where you want it to run,
    'if not, change also ThisWorkbook for Workbooks("WorkbookName.Extension")
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName")
    
    With ws
        'This is to get the last row with data, so change Z for whichever column
        'has the last row with data
        Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row
        'This gets the last column with data, assuming you have all your headers in row 1
        Dim LastCol As Long: LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        'Put your whole range into a variable
        Dim FilterRange As Range: Set FilterRange = .Range("A1", .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
        'Filter by your criteria
        FilterRange.AutoFilter 1, "No"
        FilterRange.AutoFilter 3, "Yes"
        'Now find the first row without data in column AB
        Dim FirstRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row
        Set FilterRange = .Range("AB2:AB" & LastRow)
        Dim cell As Range
        For Each cell In FilterRange
            If cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
                FirstRow = cell.Row
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cell
        'Fill all your visible cells in Range AB with Yes
        .Range("AB" & FirstRow & ":AB" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) = "Yes"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: There were some errors in the code that you provided, but I just tweaked it a bit and made it work. thank you!!